# Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle - finding uncertainty in wavelength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wavelength

I am confused about this problem:
[image]

I needed to find the uncertainty of a wavelength using Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. In the solution, they differentiated $λ=c/f$ with respect to frequency to get $\frac{-c}{f^{2}}$.  λ is then substituted back in to get $\frac{- λ^{2}}{c}$. $Δf$ had already been found, so the final equation to find $Δλ$ was:

$$Δλ = \frac{- λ^{2}}{c}*Δf$$

Which honestly makes no sense to me. Why is it necessary to differentiate λ? I was thinking that the final equation would be something like:

$$Δλ = \frac{c}{Δf}$$

since $λ = \frac{c}{f}$. Why wouldn't my method work?

Comment: I remember this question being posed to the class on my first day of senior-level modern physics laboratory.  There were about ten of us in the class, all good students, and *zero* people understood for a good five minutes.  It's a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to why differentiation, we are talking about basic calculus.  You want to find out how $\lambda$ varies with $f$.

$\lambda =\frac{c}{f}$

$\frac{d\lambda}{df}=-\frac{c}{f^2}=-\frac{\lambda ^2}{c}$

$d\lambda=-\frac{\lambda ^2}{c}\ df$

Change the differentials to $\Delta$'s and you get what they have.  Your way is incorrect in that

$d\lambda\neq \frac{c}{df}$

Comment: Emm... no, the biggest error here is that he took the negative of the speed of light, the rest is relatively simple algebra and dimensional analysis.

Comment: @GarethMeredith : Where are you seeing a negative speed of light?  Did you even read his question?

Comment: I sure did... did you? He wrote $\frac{-c}{f}$ - now tell me why this is wrong? Can you, or won't you?

Comment: That negative arises from taking a derivative. It has nothing to do with a negative speed of light. It correctly indicates that $\Delta\lambda$ is negative when $\Delta f$ is positive. True because  $\lambda$ is inversely proportional to $f$.

Comment: Tell me what I am misunderstanding, because (-c) no matter what the derivative is, is still an illegal conclusion within physics.... You cannot have a (-c) even as a smudge factor to find a derivative?

Comment: The negative sign, must be removed in my opinion so that these ''negative values'' to the speed of light are removed because I was always taught such a constuction is illegal mathematical-wise. Surely you'd have to distribute an extra negative sign so that (-c) does not appear.?

Comment: Why don't you take the derivative yourself. If you do it correctly you will get the same thing.  By the way, that expression is not even the OP's.  He is quoting someone else's solution which you would know if you read the question, so if it were in error, which it is not, it would not be his.

Comment: If your only problem is the position of the negative sign, then I would say it is a personal problem rather than a mathematical one.

Comment: Ok, but as a physicist, I can assure you, (-c) is still an illegal move. You cannot do this... only a pure mathematician without a background in physics could ignore such a thing... of course, you can always take the negative of a velocity which must be less than the speed of light. But I agree on your last statement, if the negative sign in the OP problem, we know what to do to fix it,,, we simply distribute the negative sign again meaning the wavelength responds accordingly negative, but I will state again, (-c) is simply not allowed in physics.

Comment: $\lambda = \frac{c}{f}$

The derivative gives

${d\lambda}{dt^{-1}} = \frac{- \lambda}{c}$

but in physics the speed of light can never be negative so the only formula I can see that would make sense would result in an inequality:

${d\lambda}{dt^{-1}} = \frac{-v}{f^2} < \frac{\lambda}{c}$

This now gives us the correct us the correct application, in which we strictly remove the idea of a negative speed of light.

Comment: Disagree and done.

Comment: I don't understand what you are disagreeing with? I am not trying to cause an argument, you can look for yourself online if you don't believe me that you cannot take the negative of a speed of light?

Answer (score -6):

A wavelength has dimensions of a length: One way to apply the uncertainty principle is by application of an uncertainty between space and time:

$\Delta t \Delta x$

and so the uncertainty is a length squared quantity

$c \Delta t \Delta x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$

This is the spacetime uncertainty principle. Interpretation into the wavelength is using natural units now of $c = 1$

$\Delta t \Delta \lambda \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$

**edit**: A poster has rightfully pointed out the dimensions are not entirely correct, but this was because I was attempting to teach the poster about dimensions. This edit is now to show the correct formula:

$\int q \cdot dp = action$

In generalized coordinates in which the wavelength (times) the momentum gives you an action. I fear people are quick to put down a post and not realize when someone is actually trying to help. Outside of generalized coordinates it can also be seen as

$\int \lambda \cdot dp = action$

or even

$\int p \cdot \Delta \lambda \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$

Be aware though, that the order of multiplication between these quantities is always important. So why... simply because they do not commute

$[p,x] \geq \hbar$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94703/discussion-on-answer-by-gareth-meredith-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle-fin).

Comment: Then chat away, why do my posts keep getting negatives from people when they won't give up on the explanation of why? Is this not clearly a site for trolls that are abusing their ability to down vote a post? I won't be returning thank you, I can see right through this place.

Comment: Another user pointed out already that the dimensions of your first few inequalities don't even have matching dimensions, and so can't possibly be true. And even if they were true, they don't really address the question.

Comment: Yet I have explained, the OP's equations where not true either... I did this intentionally to teach, not to cause confusion. I was actually hoping the OP would learn something, instead you are using the downgrade as a tool to discourage learning which is why I give up with this place. I clearly know what I am talking about, or the subject brought up would have been beyond me... but it wasn't. It was beyond the ability of people here to understand my motives.

Comment: But no... it has to be about ''how I am wrong''.... instead, I proved time and time again, I know how to do dimensional analysis, a small look at previous posts of mine, will clearly address this issue.

Comment: He wrote $\frac{-c}{f}$ indicating he has taken the speed of light as a negative value. This is quite clear and I don't know why I need to explain this.